# How to call a "ID" div & spesific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am correctly got this code:

```
<a id="home-slidetotext2" href="#main">Go Main</a>
```

The link is working, but it send me to "main" div,
but the issue is that the "main" div, is not in the top on my screen,
what I wanna do is set that the TOP element on my screen will be the "main" div when I press on that link.

How I can do this?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Either apply the necessary `id` to the intended target element, or move the currently targeted element to the required position in the DOM. I would go with the former rather than the latter, just seems like a better solution since you won't need to move around elements or duplicate `id` selectors that may already have styles attributed to them.

Comment: the id is good, and the position is good. it appears to be happenind becouse the elemnt "above" it got an "absulot position. so he keep him on the top of the screen after pressing on the "main" link

Comment: can u share your codes in fiddle?

Comment: hi, is on a live site: http://www.ronitlibling.co.il/ the line that call the relevant div is:  <a id="home-slidetotext2" href="#main"><span class="screen-reader-text">עבור לתוכן</span></a>

Answer (score 0):

When you click on that link send you to element with id #main.
If you want go to specific point, put `name="xyz"` where you want to go and link `<a  href="#xyz">Go XYZ</a>`

Comment: yeah i am getting reffered to the div with an id "main", but he appears in the middle of my screen. i want to that the "main" will be on the top on my screen and not apear in the middle (after i pressed the link).

Comment: If the page is too short the browser don't add space under. Try to decrease the height of you browser window.

Comment: it appears to be happening becouse the elemnt "above" it got an "absulot" position attribude. so he keep him on the top of the screen after pressing on the "main" link

Comment: hi, the code in on a live site: ronitlibling.co.il the line that call the relevant div is: <a id="home-slidetotext2" href="#main"><span class="screen-reader-text">עבור לתוכן</span></a>

Comment: There is an error in js try to correct it. Everithing seems googd.